# Object... Object[] and formatting

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, java-8

I have different types of data (it could be String, Integer...).
Here is a simple example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    before("one");
}

public static void before(Object... datas ) {
    go(1, datas);
}

public static void go(Object...params ) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} is the same as {1}", params));
}
```

I want this : `"1 is the same as one"` but got this `"1 is the same as [Ljava.lang.Object;@4554617c"`

It seems the problem is in my params, I would like an array like this [1, "one"] but instead "one" is encapsulated inside an array. I would like something to "flat". Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: you should change `before` method's params. like this: `before(1,"one");` then it will work correctly

Comment: yes I pass to go() an array : array[0]=1 (the integer) et array[1]=nested array (containing the value "one"). Basically I want to flat that to get a single array merging values from nested array. Don't know if I make myself understood. What I would like : array[0] = 1 and array[1]="one"

Answer (score 1):

what you pass to `go` is actually 1 and and array containing "one", that is why you get that `[Ljava.lang.Object;@4554617c"`. You could change you method to:

```
public static void before(Object... datas) {
    Object[] arr = Stream.concat(Stream.of(1), Arrays.stream(datas))
                         .toArray();
    go(arr);
}
```

Comment: @AntonBoarf what is your expected output?

Comment: [1, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7852e922] is the same as {1}

Comment: thanks it works. Was thinking about using flatMap() method

Answer (score 0):

from your example the formatted message always contains 2 parameters, so you can simplify it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    before("one");
}

public static void go(Object...params) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} is the same as {1}", params));
}

public static void before(Object data) {
    go(1, data);
}
```